# URL navigation bar in iOS webview

Tags: ios, mobile, webview, navigation

I created a simple webview that loads
a pre-defined website in iOS app.

```
   NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://jihadkawas.com"];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[Webview loadRequest:req];
```

how can i add a URL BAR, so that user can access any url? like normal browsers?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a Textfield (the URL-Bar where Users can type in the website's address.

```
UITextField *urlBarTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,40)];
[self.view addSubview:urlBarTextField];
```

And you need a go button or wait until the user pressed return on the Keyboard. 
In the called method (either the Button target method or `-(void)textField: shouldReturn:`)

You need to load the new URL and display it in the UIWebView

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlBarTextField.text];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

That's it ;)

Comment: where should i write the first and the second code? in the .h or .m file?

Comment: This is all implementation so .m. I would recommend you to read some raywenderlich basic iOS Tutorials. Then this will be totally clear to you

Answer (score 0):

Just create a text field and a go button,

when the url presses the go button---

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:textField.text];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[Webview loadRequest:req];
```

There you go